# Regex to match the first occurrence of a string

Tags: regex

I have this string:

> City - This is some text. This is some more - and continues here.

I would like to split the string at the first ' - ' to find 'city' (just a sample word, it can be other words as well). Plus to find the rest of the text after ' - '.

I constructed this expression:

```
(^[\D\W\S]*)( - )([\D\W\S]*)
```

But this finds the last occurrence of ' - ' instead of the first one.

How can I stop at the first occurrence ?

Comment: Most languages have functions to split a string by a certain character and even let you limit the number of splits. You should use such a function. If you let us know which language you are using, we could help you more.

Comment: It depends on the regex engine.  What are you using?

Comment: Come on guys, why downvote this? It's a fair question, he did put some research effort into it, and he showed what he tried. This is a lot more than we get from most newcomers. So, from me, user1391459, welcome to StackOverflow, and hang in there! (Also it's a good idea to choose a better username :))

Comment: As an aside, how did you come up with `[\D\W\S]`? It means "a character that is either not a digit or not alphanumeric (which already includes "not a digit") or not a whitespace character. Therefore, it matches any character, and in regex, that's what the dot (`.`: Any character (except newlines)) is for. Unless you're using JavaScript in which case you might need `[\S\s]` if you don't have an option that allows you to specify singleline mode, so the dot really matches *any* character.

Comment: I need the expression to match a certain text in Drupal Feeds  xpath parser. The dot is not enough as it should also match newlines. I left it out here by mistake because of my testing. [\S\s].* does not work. I actually use [\D\W\S\n] now. I found for php the alternative /(.*)/sU but that does not work in the xpath parser.

Comment: @user1391459: Not `[\S\s].*`! Use `[\S\s]` *instead* of the dot (so the result is `[\S\s]*` or `[\S\s]*?`. That's all you need.

Comment: [\S\s] indeed works. Sorry, thought I tested that as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to explicitly forbid the dash to be part of the first group:

```
^([^-]*) - (.*)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
([^-]*)  # Match any number of characters except dashes
\ - \    # Match a dash (surrounded by spaces)
(.*)     # Match anything that follows
```

However, this would fail if your string *could*  contain a dash in the first group (just not surrounded by spaces). If that's the case, then you can make use of lazy quantifiers:

```
^(.*?) - (.*)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^        # Start of string
(.*?)    # Match any number of characters, as few as possible
\ - \    # Match a dash (surrounded by spaces)
(.*)     # Match anything that follows
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks also for the very quick response. Because the text also has newlines and because there is a number at the end that should be left out, this is what works: ^(.*?) - ([\D\W\S\n]*)\d{10}

Comment: Great, glad to hear it. But you'd better use `[\S\s]*` instead of `[\D\W\S\n]*`.